# Excel 2013 - Power Query, Background refresh. Method 'Refresh' of object 'WorkbookConnection' failed

Tags: excel, vbscript, excel-2013, powerquery, vba

I have a workbook which contains several Power Query queries (data source is SQL server) which I am trying to refresh via task scheduler on a remote server. I have a VBscript which opens an Excel file (Refresh Engine) which then refreshes the file containing the queries (Target File). It's structured in this way as each month the target file has it's name changed and a copy is archived as a historic log.

**If I log on to the remote server and kick the VBscript off manually the code runs with no error.** However, when the script is run via scheduled tasks the Refresh Engine fails with the error recorded as '-2147417848, Method 'Refresh' of object 'WorkbookConnection' failed'.

I've tried changing numerous connection settings without any success. Can anybody help?

The code I am using to refresh the queries within the target workbook is as follows. (Please note various variables have already been created and bound in previous subs).

```
On Error GoTo ErrLog
For Each Cn In CurStr.Connections
    Log.WriteLine (Now() & " Looking at " & Cn.Name)
    bg = Cn.OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery
    Cn.OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery = False
    Log.WriteLine (Now() & " Refreshing " & Cn.Name)
    Cn.Refresh
    Cn.OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery = bg
Next
Log.WriteLine (Now() & " Refreshing model")
CurStr.Model.Refresh
On Error GoTo 0
Exit Sub
```

Comment: What account is the scheduled task running under?

Comment: A dedicated user that we use for various other scheduled jobs. Any passwords required for SQL authorisation are saved in the workbook.

Comment: Are you logging into the server as that user when testing the manual run?

Comment: Yes, I've also tried as 2 other users. It appears that as long as the VBscript is kicked off by a user logged on to the machine it will succeed. Just not using scheduled tasks.

Comment: Well, my code to refresh a power query is as follows: dim con as workbookConnection, for each con in ActiveWorkbook.Queries If Left(con.name, 7) = "Query -" Then dim cname as string, cname = con.name, with activeworkbook.Connections(cname).OLEDBConnection .backgroundQuery = True, .Refresh end with, end if, next. Works for me (y)